# Best way to implement a request response pattern that is extendable

Tags: c#

OK,

I have to create a C# library that can send commands to a device and process the command specific responses and broadcasts over a serial port (or other communications method). The library must also be able to handle request and response extensions held in other libraries as certain devices implement an extended command set, but it must be possible to choose whether these extended commands are utilised (I guess using reflection in the client app). I have created a class of type Packet that is able to create the packet and add its payload, calculate its checksum and write the packet to the stream.

```
public class Packet
{
    internal PacketHeaderType Header { get; private set; }
    internal List<byte> Payload { get; private set; }

    protected int PayloadLength { get { return Payload.Count; } }
    protected byte HeaderByte { get { return (byte)((Convert.ToByte(Header) << 4) | PayloadLength); } } //we need to add the packet length to the lower nibble of the header before sending


    public Packet(PacketHeaderType header, List<byte> payload) 
    {
        this.Header = header;
        this.Payload = new List<byte>(payload);
    }

    public Packet(PacketHeaderType headerByte)
    {
        this.Header = headerByte;
        this.Payload = new List<byte>();
    }

    internal byte XorByte
    {
        get
        {
            Byte xorByte = Convert.ToByte(HeaderByte);

            for (int i = 0; i < PayloadLength; i++)
                xorByte ^= Payload.ToArray()[i];

            return xorByte;

        }
    }

    public async Task WriteAsync(Stream stream, bool flush = true, CancellationToken token = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        var buffer = new List<byte>();


        buffer.Add(HeaderByte);


        if (Payload != null && PayloadLength > 0)
        {
            buffer.AddRange(Payload);
        }

        buffer.Add(XorByte);

        await stream.WriteAsync(buffer.ToArray(), 0, buffer.Count);

        if (flush)
        {
            await stream.FlushAsync();
        }

    }
}
```

I have also created child classes that implement Type packet for each of the valid commands. 
Finally I have also created a class of type PacketHandler that is able to read bytes from a stream and create it into a packet object.

The way I envisage using the library would be like this:

```
public async string GetCmdStnSoftwareVersion()
{
    var msgReq = new CmdStnSoftwareVersionReqMessage();
    await msgReq.WriteAsync(sPort.BaseStream);
    await var response = msgReq.GetResponse(5); //5 = timeout in seconds!

    return String.Format("{0}.{1}", response.Major, response.Minor);
}
```

What I am stuck on is a good pattern and/or example implementation for handling responses which is compatible with implementing the extension libraries. Can anyone provide input?

Comment: great! what's your question?

Comment: I am stuck on is a good pattern and/or example implementation for handling responses and implementing the extension libraries.

Comment: you won't get an answer on this, as it is primarily opinion based. Ask 3 programmers, you get 4 different answers :)

Comment: You may be less chirping if you post this on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/?as=1

Comment: Thanks Peter, I have also posted on there: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/64897/request-response-pattern-in-c